# InternalOAuthError when using passport-linkedin strategy

Tags: node.js, oauth, passport.js, linkedin-api

I'm working with passport-linkedin and I'm getting this error.

```
InternalOAuthError: failed to obtain request token
    at /Users/davey/code/node/appify-frontend/node_modules/passport-linkedin/node_modules/passport-oauth/lib/passport-oauth/strategies/oauth.js:196:36
    at /Users/davey/code/node/appify-frontend/node_modules/passport-linkedin/lib/passport-linkedin/strategy.js:80:19
    at passBackControl (/Users/davey/code/node/appify-frontend/node_modules/passport-linkedin/node_modules/passport-oauth/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:397:13)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/davey/code/node/appify-frontend/node_modules/passport-linkedin/node_modules/passport-oauth/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:409:9)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:908:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
GET /oauth/linkedin 500 1074ms - 786b
```

Here's what my setup looks like

```
exports.setup = function (config) {
  var passport = require('passport');
  var LinkedinStrategy = require('passport-linkedin').Strategy;

  passport.use(new LinkedinStrategy({
      consumerKey: config.linkedin.clientID,
      consumerSecret: config.linkedin.clientSecret,
      callbackURL: config.linkedin.callbackURL
    },
    function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
      console.log(token, tokenSecret, profile);
      return done(null, true);
    }
  ));
};
```

and my routing setup is as follows

```
router
    .get('/', 
        function(req, res, next) {
            console.log("[OAuth2:redirect:query]:", JSON.stringify(req.query));
            console.log("[OAuth2:redirect:body]:", JSON.stringify(req.body));
            next();
          },
        passport.authenticate('linkedin', {
        failureRedirect: '/settings/connected-accounts',
        session: false
    }))

    .get('/callback', passport.authenticate('linkedin', {
        failureRedirect: '/settings/connected-accounts',
        session: false
    }), function (req, res){
        res.redirect('/settings/connected-accounts');
    });
```

In the same app, I've setup twitter and facebook oauth, both of which work very well. I have no idea what's causing this error and have tried everything.

In my linkedin developer account, I've configured everything as should be.

Authorized Redirect URLs:

`http://testdomain.ngrok.io/oauth/linkedin/callback`

Default "Accept" Redirect URL:

`http://testdomain.ngrok.io/settings/connected-accounts`

I first used a localhost url running on port 9000, but when that failed, I exposed my app running locally to a live url, but I still had the same error.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How long have you had the error for? There could be something up on LinkedIn's end?

Comment: Been like that for about 15 hours now

Answer (score 1):

The `InternalOAuthError` is related to passport-oauth1 ( https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-linkedin/blob/master/lib/strategy.js ) , but you use OAuth2 according to your routing setup. So try switching to [passport-linkedin-oauth2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-linkedin-oauth2)